# JavaScript code analysis in VS Code - preventing redeclaration of variable etc

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, phpstorm, webstorm

I PhpStorm/WebStorm there is a built-in feature that will alert if you have mistakes like declaring a variable twice. i.e.:

```js
const testVar = 'testing' 

// 10 lines later 

const testVar = 'running'
```

This should show an alert.

Is there a VS Code extension/feature to alert these kind of mistakes?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to use the [ESLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) extension.